# How can I dynamically render an image into a react component view?

Tags: reactjs, image

I am new to react native developments and I need to show information of an array (which contains picture object) as a tiled view. Thumbnail of the picture is in 'data:' uri scheme, so I tried following code segment. Problem is, thumbnail image is not loaded.

```
<img class="thumbimage" source={{ uri: picture.thumbnail }} alt="thumbnail"/>
```

Complete render method is as follows.

```
render() {
    const { searchName, drawings, currentDrawing, currentIndex } = this.state;

    return (
      <div class="gallery-view">
        <div className="gallery-view-searchbar">
          <div className="gallery-view-searchcomponent">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Search by drawing name"
              value={searchName}
              onChange={this.onChangeSearchName}
            />
            <div className="input-group-append">
              <button
                className="gallery-view-search-drawing-button"
                type="button"
                onClick={this.searchName}
              >
                Search
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="gallery-view-search-results">
          <ul className="list-group">
            {drawings &&
              drawings.map((picture, index) => (
                <div className="picture-tile">
                  <div>{picture.name}</div>
                  <div>{picture.description}</div>
                  {/* <Image></Image> */}
                  <div>
                    <img
                      class="thumbimage"
                      source={{ uri: picture.thumbnail }}
                      alt="thumbnail"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: How are you importing the image tag? Did you confirm `picture.thumbnail` exists?

Comment: @jewishmoses yes. Debugging shows information of 'picture'.thumbnail variable as, thumbnail:
data: Array(16179)
[0 … 9999]
[10000 … 16178]
length: 16179
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
type: "Buffer"

Comment: I have finally managed to solve this issue by setting 'src' instead of 'source' as  src={Buffer.from(picture.thumbnail).toString()}.

Comment: @dds perfect, exactly what i was looking for, but for me `src=` worked just fine.